# Using AWSTask to get logins from cognitio

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the following code used to refresh my token synchronously:

```
- (AWSTask<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *) logins
{
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult: @{ @"com.example.test": _uniqueIdentifireForThisUser}];
}
```

I was told the tokens only last 1 hour and hopefully this refreshes it.  But how do I call above? I get an incompatiable pointer error.

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *login = [self logins];
```

The error relates to AWSTask.  How do I get the tokens form above? I am using Federated Identities.

Comment: Have't use `cognito`, however your code doesn't seem to refresh the token, it always does the same thing - create a dictionary with an already known value.

Comment: Taken from an AWS employee here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000735/aws-ios-sdk-2-4-0-cognito-documentation/40008653

Comment: Still, the code in this question doesn't seem to do any server calls to refresh the token. If you already have access to `_uniqueIdentifireForThisUser`, then why struggling to wrap it inside an `AWSTask` object?

Comment: I am confused then on how to use an identityId and token.

Comment: I am trying to figure out roles identityIds and tokens and how to make sure the user remains logged in.

Comment: I have this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393152/verifying-user-is-authenticated-using-aws-ios-sdk/41397696#41397696